# Suppress event times in week view?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, ical

Within `iCal` the preferences settings let choose the use of event times
in month view.

I would like to obtain the same choice for the **week** view.

I'm actually using iCal on Snow Leopard, which I will shortly upgrade to Lion and Mountain Lion.
Is this choice possible within iCal on these different OS X versions?
Is there any progress on this possibility through these versions of the OS (this will be a key incentive to accelerate the OS X upgrade in such a case).

Additionally, is there any documentation about this level of tuning for iCal.

Comment: I looked at `defaults` and it's not an option there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
It is possible from the `Preferences > General` menu of `Calendar` to activate the display of event times within the *week* view too:

```
Show event times
```